# Delete and replace the last line in ScintillaNET

Tags: c#, windows, forms, scintilla

I need a code snippet to delete the last line of ScintillaNET control
and append a line to it. I tried this but didn't work:

```
        scintilla1.GoTo.Line(scintilla1.Lines.Count);
        int nowPosition = scintilla1.Caret.Position;
        scintilla1.Text.Remove(nowPosition);
```

Comment: have you reference the [ScintillaNet Web Site](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: I didn't find anything useful in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about being late. I found this post and was sad to see nothing good (not your fault) so I kept looking around and found this:

```
((INativeScintilla)scintilla).DeleteBack()
```

This will simulate a backspace key press (remove 1 character on the left of the cursor). It isnt pretty but it could get the job done for you. Worked for me :)

For you, you could store the cursor position in an int, set it to the end, 'backspace' all the characters you want, then set it back.

Comment: I have come across memory corruption when using this method. Haven't found any alternatives though >.<